# PHP Execute Command Line from Page

Tags: php, browser, safari, wkhtmltopdf, wsh

I have a block of PHP code that passes a URL to a plugin called `wkhtmltopdf` and renders a PDF of the page using webkit.

My code works fine in IE and Firefox which are the main two we use but some of our executives use Safari and the code does not run.

```
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST'){

  // DEVELOPMENT CODE
  $newPDF = md5($qid . time()). '.pdf';
  $current = getcwd() . '\\exports\\';

  $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
  $WshShell->exec($current.'makeWKPDF.bat "'.$fileURL.'&ref=nomenu" '.$newPDF); 

  // had to add this because shell isnt waiting for the file to finish before continuning 
  sleep(10);

  // get the contents of the new PDF file 
  $pdf = file_get_contents($toolURL."exports/".$newPDF);

  // push the PDF File to the browser
  header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Initiative '.$intID.' Export.pdf"'); 

  // push the PDF to the browser
  echo $pdf;

  // delete the PDF 
  @unlink($current.$newPDF);
}
```

My first and only guess at this point would be that Safari doesn't support the `new COM` I am creating?

Can anyone confirm if that's the case and a possible work-around; been doing some research and can't find anything on it.

**UPDATE**
I also found that this does not work in IE8 either. I think both issues are pointing to how PHP is creating the COM object but I am not sure of another way to get that to work.